# On Click Javascript - New Methods

Tags: apex, javascript

This is a fresher question.

Is it possible to create a new method as part of the "onclick javascript" code on custom button.

For example the following pseudo code can  explain what I am trying to achieve

```
<--code begin

method1()
{


}


if(condition1 is true)
{
   method1();
}

}
--> code ends
```

Is it possible to achieve something like this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. You can declare methods inside an onclick event and call them later. JavaScript does allow functions to be embedded inside other functions. I've used this technique to help organize complex button code. You have to use the function keyword, as normal.

```
function x() {
    alert("Hello World");
}
if({!not ispickval(Lead.LeadStatus, "Ready to convert")}) x();
```